# grep -f A B - How to reverse and get lines NOT containing words from A

Tags: grep

I use `grep -f A B` to get lines from B containing words in list A. 
How can i get lines from B not containing words from A? Or can this not be done with grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-v` option to `grep` to show non-matching lines.

```
grep -f A -v B > C
```

or

```
grep -v -f A B > C
```

When you have an option that takes a parameter, the parameter has to follow the option immediately. This is basic Unix command syntax, I didn't think I had to spell it out. Did you just start using Unix yesterday?

Comment: my bad, i use `grep -f A B > C`so i need to use `grep -f -v A B > C` or `grep -fv A B > C` both are not working :(